# js using object literals for var replacement

Tags: javascript, object-literal

for the longest time now i've used object literals to replace multiple var statements within my code. here's a typical example:

```
(function(){
  var replaceVars = {};
  function x(){
    replaceVars.num=886;
}
  function y(){
    x();
    replaceVars.cal = replaceVars.num*99;
    return replaceVars.cal;
  }
})();
```

so my question is: is there anything wrong with this? i mean the up sides i can see are that: 1) there is only one var statement within the whole of my code. 2) within the closure all children can access it(which means replaceVars properties become global within the scope of the closure. it's like making a global-like child object (the closure) within the true global object(the window)  3) i can pre-define properties that are ready to go immediately:

> var replaceVars={
>           something1:"some value",
>           something2:"some other value"
>       }

so can anyone think of any downsides to my way of doing things?

Comment: why are you doing this? to what end?

Comment: There's nothing with multiple `var` statements in JavaScript. Just make sure they all occur at the top of the function they're used in.

Comment: well after using jsLint for the first time many years ago and it complaining about too many vars i started doing it this way and it just stuck with me. plus it seems a lot neater than declaring all your vars at once: var x,y,z,count chocula;

Comment: @jbabey this is just a way for me to organize my code which then became a habit.

Comment: @codewombat take every "error" jslint gives you with a 10 tonne grain of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything *wrong* with using a container object. Though, I'd make a habit with it of declaring the variables needed for the related code:

```
var replaceVars = {
    num: null,
    cal: null
};
```

But, then again, this works as well:

```
(function () {
  var num, cal;

  function x(){
    num = 886;
  }

  function y(){
    x();
    cal = num * 99;
    return cal;
  }
})();
```

Comment: hmmm... is declaring the properties before hand just a good practice or is there a benefit to it memory/speed wise?

Comment: @codewombat It's just for your own sake, offering a clue about the following code. So you don't have to scour through all of your code to determine which properties are being used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you just want to hide objects within another object and, for example, make them accessible via methods only, I would do it like this:

```
var objects = (function() {
  var x = 42;
  var y = 12;

  var container = {};
  container.getX = function getX() {
    return x;
  }
  container.getY = function getY() {
    return y;
  }
  container.getSum = function getSum() {
    return x + y;
  }

  return container;
})();
```

That's a lot easier to read, in my opinion.

Comment: Having read the comments underneath the original question now, I doubt my answer is what you were looking for... ;)